# Battery symbol in circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Is it possible to make `circuitikz` draw battery-symbols like this:

[image]

Comment: I know nothing about circutikz, but you can have a look at the battery symbol in the tikz circuits library.

Comment: Which "tikz circuits library"? How to use it? Could you give an example please?

Comment: See the pgfmanual http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf p.311

Comment: @cjorssen: Thanks, I have found it in the manual. This led me to post another wuestion: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33660/relationship-between-tikz-circuit-library-and-circuitikz

Comment: @cjorssen: You should compose a MWE as answer so this question can be marked as answered.

Comment: @PeterGrill Done.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165177/including-signs-to-battery-in-circuitikz

Comment: In `circuitikz`: `\draw (0,0) to[battery1] (1,0);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, I cannot provide any circuitikz solution. The following uses the tikz circuits library introduced in pgf 2.1 (and 2.0-cvs).

[image: An example with a battery]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
  \draw (0,0) to [battery={info={$e_1$}}] ++(2,0) to
  [current direction' = {info = {$i$}, near start}, 
   resistor = {info = {$R$}, near end}] ++(0,3) to 
  [bulb] ++(-2,0) to[current direction' = {info = {$i$}}] (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `battery1`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\tikz{
  \draw (0,0) to [battery1] (1,0);
  }

\end{document}
```

[image: battery1 output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Perhaps you could turn this into a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Thank you for completing the MWE! Can you upload an image to the StackExchange servers, instead of using the PDF from dropbox? As you can see, the PDF is not able to be displayed as an image. If you need some help on getting an image, you can see this post: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5954/most-efficient-workflow-for-displaying-imgur-hosted-output-of-tex-friends-so?cb=1 You may also want to email the StackExchange staff via the ["Contact Us"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/contact) link to have your accounts here combined. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2):

I did it in such way:

```
\makeatletter
\ctikzset{bipoles/battery/width/.initial=.1}
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/battery/height}}{battery}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/battery/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/battery/width}}{
        \pgf@circ@res@step = -\ctikzvalof{bipoles/battery/width}
        \pgf@circ@Rlen \divide \pgf@circ@res@step by 2

        \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{.5\pgf@circ@res@down}}

        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@step}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@step}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}

        \pgfusepath{draw}
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0):

## Source

Complementing what @RichardHDowney answered. The [circuitikz manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf) contains all the information about the circuit elements that can be used with circuitikz, in section **3.2.4 Stationary sources** of this manual two batteries will appear `battery` and `battery1`.

## MWE with `battery`

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
      \draw (0,0) to [battery] (1,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: output with battery]

## MWE with `battery1`

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
      \draw (0,0) to [battery1] (1,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output with battery1]