# Opposite poles battery in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

This might be a simple question, but I would like the battery positive pole to be to the left, and to the right as the default,

```
(0,0) to [battery, v=$\varepsilon$] (2,0)
```

Also, is there an option within `circuitikz` to draw only one pair of poles instead of 2? I have seen the following solution
[Battery symbol in circuitikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33649/battery-symbol-in-circuitikz)
but I would be happy to know if a `circuitikz` solution exists.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I can come up with is to simply reverse the direction in which you place the `battery`. So instead of `\draw (0,0) to [battery, ...] (2,0)` you use `\draw (2,0) to [battery, ..] (0,0)` (as is the case in the second example below).

If you do not want to reverse the direction in which you place the nodes, you could  use `rotate=180,transform shape` option.  This unfortunately also ends up producing a mirror image of the text, which can be remedied by applying a `\rotatebox{180}{}` to the voltage label (two 180 rotations of the text returns the text back to the original orientation).
By default, this place the direction arrow at the bottom. If you desire this at the top, you can use `\circuitikzbasekey/bipole/voltage/position =below` as is the case in the examples below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) to [battery, v=$\varepsilon$] (2,0) node [right] {Default};
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (2,0) node [right] {Reverse  coordinates} to
    [battery, v=$\varepsilon$,
        \circuitikzbasekey/bipole/voltage/position = below] (0,0) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) to 
    [rotate=180,transform shape,
        battery, v=\rotatebox{180}{$\varepsilon$},
        \circuitikzbasekey/bipole/voltage/position = below] (2,0) 
    node {Rotate text and symbol};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

In recente versions of Circuitikz, you can use the `invert` option to invert the poles of bipolar components, but it won't rotate labels or the arrow that indicates the rise of potential. That said, you can always set the arrow's direction using `v<= , v>=` where the point of the less or greater tha symbol is the direction of the arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) to [battery, v=$\varepsilon$] (2,0) node [right] {Default};
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) to [battery, v<=$\varepsilon$,invert] (2,0) node [right] {Inverted};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result
[image: Result]

Notice that `v<=` made the arrow point to the left in the inverted example .

PS.: Sorry for my broken English

Answer (score 2):

To change the circuitikz defaults you may have to alter its **.sty** and **.tex** files. Instead you can change direction of the battery terminals by changing the order of the component directions. You can also use circuitikz' label mechanism (l^ and l_) to place the name above or below the component.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[european,american]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) to [battery, l^={$\varepsilon$}] (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (2,0) to [battery, l_={$\varepsilon$}] (0,0);
    \draw (4,0) to [battery, l^={$\varepsilon$}] (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```