# TikZ/CircuiTikZ battery symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits

How can I get a battery symbol like this from either CircuiTikZ or TikZ's circuit libraries? I haven't been able to find any that have a thick negative terminal. `pst-circ`'s `\battery` command is exactly what I want, but I'd prefer to stick to TikZ.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
  \draw (0, 1) to [battery] (0, 0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The third answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33649/battery-symbol-in-circuitikz?rq=1 does almost everything for you.  You just hve to change the line thickness.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, that changes the thickness of both terminals, I only want the negative terminal to be thicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I should have mentioned that you also have to split the component into two paths to implement two different line widths,

Note, you probably could reuse `\linethickness` instead of `\tempwidth`.  A quick search of sty files only found it used in `geometry` and `gkpmac`(?).  Besides, local changes won't get out of `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\newlength{\tempwidth}

\makeatletter
\ctikzset{bipoles/battery/width/.initial=.1}
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/battery/height}}{battery}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/battery/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/battery/width}}{
        \pgf@circ@res@step = -\ctikzvalof{bipoles/battery/width}
        \pgf@circ@Rlen \divide \pgf@circ@res@step by 2
        \tempwidth=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth

        \pgfsetlinewidth{\tempwidth}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}

        \pgfsetlinewidth{2\tempwidth}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@step}{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@step}{.5\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 1) to [battery] (0, 0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: battery]

Comment: Your battery symbol should be included into `circuitikz` as an option in selecting of battery symbols.

Comment: @Zarko - I have no control over circuitikz, but I can add it to my collection http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/index.htm

Comment: well, maybe you would write to author of circuitikz, that he include your impressive collection images. Thank you for link, it will be very useful for me.

Comment: I have included the symbol to circuitikz named "battery2". It will be part of the next release and can be tried using the gitversion from here http://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/